# how to handle null safety during api call flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, dart-null-safety

am trying to do an API call where am getting an error to hangle null safety variable must be assigned.

here is my code

```
Future<LoginResponseModel> loginCustomer(
      String username, String password) async {
    LoginResponseModel model;

    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(Config.tokenURL,
          data: {
            "username": username,
            "password": password,
          },
          options: Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          }));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        model = LoginResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
    return model;
  }
```

exception am getting

> The non-nullable local variable 'model' must be assigned before it can
> be used. Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's
> assigned on every execution path.dart
> (not_assigned_potentially_non_nullable_local_variable)

is there any solution to handle this

tried "?" it's not working.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1eYn.png)

Comment: You don't initialize `model` along all possible code paths.  You either must initialize it along all code paths (such as if `response.statusCode != 200` or if a `DioError` is caught) or must make `model` nullable *and* must fix the return type to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  Future<LoginResponseModel?> loginCustomer(
      String username, String password) async {
    LoginResponseModel? model;

    try {
      var response = await Dio().post(Config.tokenURL,
          data: {
            "username": username,
            "password": password,
          },
          options: Options(headers: {
            HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          }));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        model = LoginResponseModel.fromJson(response.data);
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.message);
    }
    return model;
  }
```